# Voltage Regulation Based on Ratio of Source Voltage

Tags: voltage, lm317, linear-regulator

I'd like to use the ubiquitous LM317 to regulate voltage down to 1/3 of the source voltage. Reason being, I'd like to retain the voltage information of the source (li-ion batteries).

[image: LM317]
<sub>(source: [reuk.co.uk](http://www.reuk.co.uk/OtherImages/lm317t-voltage-regulation-circuit.gif))</sub>

I've looked but haven't found any calculations online, Is it as easy as just setting the voltage divider between source and ground instead of output and ground? Or is this going to cause instability?

More info: I have a digital IC that features a battery gauge based on the source voltage (3.3-4.2V). My project has source voltage of 11.1 nominal from a 3s lithium battery. There is no practical way to get the battery gauge to work other than providing it with a ratio of the source voltage. If an LM317 will not work for this, is there another option? The Monitor is a CSR bluetooth module with a max current (for my application) of 30mA.

Comment: You are aware that monitoring _all_ batteries in series with just one chip made for monitoring a single cell invariably invites catastrophic failure anywhere between 50% and 80% into the viable lifespan, due to individual series cell imbalance? If this is _just_ fuel gauge, it may give usable result +/- 10%. If you mean protection: Just check every single cell in the pack, like you should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is, apparently, a voltage source at 1/3 your battery voltage, with enough current to drive a monitor IC at that voltage. In principle, you need something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPz9d4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Something like an LM324 should work fine for the op amp. The exact values of R1 and R2 are not critical, as long as the ratio is 2:1. You haven't specified just what monitor you're using, so there's no way to tell how much current is required. Just make sure that the op amp is capable of providing that much current. Also make sure that the amp will operate at your battery voltage.

Comment: This looks excellent thanks, how is this for PSRR? Will it function similarly to a linear voltage regulator in terms of ripple rejection would a capacitor help between R1/R2 and + pin on the op amp?

Comment: @JohnEvans If you make _anything_ that exactly modifies its output based on the power supply, what do you think will happen to Power Supply Ripple Rejection? Doesn't matter what you use, if you make a formula "Y = X/3" then any variation in X _will_ always create 1/3rd the variation in Y. Guaranteed.

Comment: With respect to the resistors (why I actually moved to the comment section) maybe 2k and 1k might be a bit on the low side for a battery operated system.

Comment: @JohnEvans - Why do you want PSRR? Think about it. If the battery voltage changes, but your circuit doesn't, what will the battery monitor do? It certainly won't accurately report the battery voltage.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, hopefully the PSRR is exactly 9.543 dB.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Only for a constant input voltage.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast, he wants the output voltage to be 1/3 of the input voltage, regardless of what the input voltage is.

Comment: @whatRoughBest thanks a bunch! PSRR is good enough with a cap in there and with the voltage equaling exactly 1/3 source, seems like an easy way to save money on LM317s tbh! These suckers only cost $.09 at volume and you get 4 channels! Only 30mA per op amp, but who cares for most things that's all you need.

Comment: @Asmyldof I think we have a new Tony in the making...